# Subject-verb agreement of the verb "cast"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I was looking for the meaning of "cast" and I came across these examples from the Cambridge Dictionary:

> to send light or shadow (= an area of darkness) in a particular direction:
> • The moon cast a white light into the room.
> • The tree cast a shadow over/on his face.
> • (figurative)Her arrival cast a shadow over/on the party (= made it less pleasant).
> https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/cast

Why for the 3 cases above we don't add an "s" to the verb after the singular nouns?

Comment: The principle parts of that verb are *cast*, *cast* and *cast*.  The subject/verb agreement that you're looking for only exists in the present tense.  There is no *casted* or *casten*, such as you might find with a more regular verb.

Comment: Because they are past tense clauses, and "cast" is the past tense form of the verb "cast".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three sentences are in past simple tense. **Cast** is one of about 10 verbs which have the same form for present simple, past simple and past participle (the most common are **put** and **hit**). If these sentences were present simple, we *would* use -s:

The moon casts a white light into the room (every night) > The moon cast a white light into the room (last night).

Compare shine/shone (or shined):

The moon shines a white light into the room (every night) > The moon shone (or shined) a white light into the room (last night).

(*Shone* is more common, but you might know *shined*.)